# Adding Positive Values Only (across multiple sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

The example formula below works perfectly in my spreadsheet if ALL the numbers are positive.  However, I would like to pull the values from the cells indicated below (from 14 different pages), but ONLY if they are positive.  How would I do that?

```
=sum(Sunday1B!M175,'Sunday 1D'!M175,Saturday1B!M175,'Saturday 1D'!M175,MondayL1!M175,Monday1!M175,TuesdayL1!M175,Tuesday1!M175,WednesdayL1!M175,Wednesday1!M175,FridayL1!M175,Friday1!M175,ThursdayL2!M175,Thursday2!M175)
```

What changes should I make to the formula above if I want to only add positive values?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to reference those cells as a range. E.g. select `A1` and add `=Sunday1B!M175`, then select `A2` and put `='Sunday 1D'!M175` and so on. The result will look like this:

```
=Sunday1B!M175
='Sunday 1D'!M175
=Saturday1B!M175
='Saturday 1D'!M175
=MondayL1!M175
=Monday1!M175
=TuesdayL1!M175
=Tuesday1!M175
=WednesdayL1!M175
=Wednesday1!M175
=FridayL1!M175
=Friday1!M175
=ThursdayL2!M175
=Thursday2!M175
```

Then select `A15` and add the `SUMIF` function:

```
=Sunday1B!M175
='Sunday 1D'!M175
=Saturday1B!M175
='Saturday 1D'!M175
=MondayL1!M175
=Monday1!M175
=TuesdayL1!M175
=Tuesday1!M175
=WednesdayL1!M175
=Wednesday1!M175
=FridayL1!M175
=Friday1!M175
=ThursdayL2!M175
=Thursday2!M175
=SUMIF(A1:A14,">0")
```

As mentioned in the formula, the `SUMIF` function will sum all cells in the range `A1:A14` whose values match the criteria `">0"` which means "greater than zero" (i.e. positive).
[image: sample range A1:A14]